# javascript : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying with below code but it is failing with error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier, on the line :

```
$.get("commonCore/templates/" + data[i].templateHtml ,function(html)
```

can somebody please help me debugging it. i am very much new to javascript and jquery

JSON :

```
[{"templateHtml":"dashBoardLeftInsight.html","classSelect":"leftpanel"},{"templateHtml":"dcdcsFilterOptions.html","classSelect":"dcdcsOptions"},{"templateHtml":"advanceFilterOptions.html","classSelect":"advancedOptions"},{"templateHtml":"reportFilterOptions.html","classSelect":"reportdashboard"}]
```

code :

```
$.getJSON('api/filterTemplate/dashboard',function (data){

            var a = new Array(data.length);
            console.log(data.length);

                $.when(function(){
                    for(var i=0;i<=data.length,i++)
                    {
                        $.get("commonCore/templates/" + data[i].templateHtml ,function(html){
                            a[i]=html;
                        });
                    }
                }).then(function(d){
                    for (var j=0;j<data.length;j++)
                    {

                        filterTemplate=Handlebars.compile(a[j]);

                        replaceFilterTemplate(data[i].classids[j]);

                    }
                })

            }
        );
```

Comment: Why don't you just follow the examples given with the documentation? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: While it s not the reason for the error message, you have another _error_: `a[i]=html;` is not correct. Because `i` will always be `data.length+1` there.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that `for` loop is processing the last iteration only...

Comment: Your for loop has syntax error as well `for(var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {` `,` instead of `;`

Comment: i fixed for loop part now handlebar is giving error. it seems like html variable is undefined as seen in chrome. any suggestion

Comment: @sameersaurav **1.** you don't return any promise for then `$.when` so `then`is executed before any of the `$.get` success callbacks. **2.** you still have the problem with the `a[i]=html` the `i` will be the same for every success callback of of the `$.get`because all of them are executed **after** the loop.

Comment: @t.niese thanks for the response. but i am noob in javascript thing. could you please help me out in resolving this

Answer (score 0):

`function(html)` is expecting a code block after it:

```
function(html) { ..some code.. }
```

Comment: a[i]=html; is inside that function only. i am sorry, i think i dint get you

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop has 2 errors:

1) replace the comma with a semicolon

2) You should change `<=` to just `<`

So your final result should look like `for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)`

Comment: i fixed for loop part now handlebar is giving error. it seems like html variable is undefined as seen in chrome. any suggestion

Comment: Since I can't see everything, try adding `console.log(arguments);` inside your first loop.  This will show you the data being returned form your web service.  You will need to debug from there.